# Output sub-folder with the latest write access

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have the following powershell command

```
get-childitem $FilePath | select {$_.Fullname}
```

This will output the name of ALL subfolders in $FilePath. How do I output the subfolder with the latest write time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after:

```
Get-ChildItem $FilePath | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime} -Descending | Select {$_.FullName} -First 1
```

If you want to see the last write time too, you can use this:

```
Get-ChildItem $FilePath | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime} -Descending | Select {$_.FullName, $_.LastWriteTime} -First 1
```

This will look at the Last Write Time of both files and folders in the given $FilePath. If you are after just files then provide the *-File* switch to Get-ChildItem, and if you are only interested in folders then provide the *-Directory* switch. Also, if you want to know the Last Write Time of any files/folders in the $FilePath including in sub-folders, then provide the *-Recurse* switch to Get-ChildItem.

If you want to see more than just the 1 file, change *-First 1* to the number of files that you want to see.

Also, if you want to instead see the file with the oldest Last Write Time, just remove the *-Descending* switch parameter to the *Sort* command.

Comment: I modified Get-Childitem so it displays the name of the folder, i.e. Get-ChildItem $FilePath | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime} -Descending | where {$_.PsIsContainer} |Select {$_.Name} -First 1

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, if you want you can simply use the -Directory switch instead of "where {$_.PsIsContainer}". Using the -Directory switch is faster, but requires PS v3.0; your "where {$_.PsIsContainer}" method is PS v2.0 compatible :)

Comment: Ahhh, we are still using PS V 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Sort the items and select the last one (default sort order is ascending):

```
Get-ChildItem $FilePath | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 1 FullName
```

Comment: This works and answers the OP's question, but if they decide they want to see, say, the 3 files with the most recent Last Write Time, the 3 files returned will be ordered backwards with the 1st being the oldest and the 3rd (last one) being the most recent. Using the -Descending switch on the Sort-Object and -First instead of -Last will put the 3 files returned in the correct order, with the 1st being the most recent, and the 3rd being the oldest.