# Output string value from Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I got the following string from [Output sub-folder with the latest write access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458186/output-sub-folder-with-the-latest-write-access)

```
Get-ChildItem $FilePath | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime} -Descending | where {$_.PsIsContainer} |Select {$_.Name} -First 1
```

But the output is :

```
$_.Name     
Username
```

The output I am trying to get is :

```
Username
```

I tried formatting the output by :

```
(Get-ChildItem $FilePath | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime} -Descending | where {$_.PsIsContainer} |Select {$_.Name} -First 1).name
```

But I'm not sure why it's not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
Get-ChildItem $filepath | ? { $_.PsIsContainer} | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -expa  Name -First 1
```

I've anticipaded the `where-object`, aka `'?'` , for better performance.

With `select-object` the `{}` are needed only for calculated properties and to avoid the coloumn name use the `-expand` parameter.